# Power Apps SharePoint date field not updating on button click

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have a button for the user to submit a SharePoint list item for review. On the click even a variable is set which updates the text status field in the SharePoint list. Here's how the status field is updated, it checks if the value is blank and sets it to draft status, if that fails then it checks the variable status update field for blanks, if nothing in the variable then it uses what is stored, otherwise it takes the value from the variable:

```
If(IsBlank(Parent.Default),"Draft",If(IsBlank(varStatusUpdate), Parent.Default,Text(varStatusUpdate)))
```

For the date field, I'm also checking for nothing on the SharePoint list, then I'm checking the same status update variable. When blank, use what is stored in the list. If the value is "pending approval" then it should get current date.

```
If(IsBlank(Parent.Default),Blank(),If(IsBlank(varStatusUpdate), Parent.Default, If(varStatusUpdate="Pending Approval", Now(),Parent.Default)))
```

When testing the updated `Now()` value appears on the screen but it isn't saved to the list. When published to SharePoint the value is never saved or updated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your relevant `Patch()` function, or whatever is sending the final results up to SharePoint?

Comment: There is no use of the ```Patch()``` function which seems fine for the numeric and text fields. The submit button logic is ```Set(varStatusUpdate, Text("Pending Approval")); SubmitForm(SharePointForm1);```

Comment: Sounds like you need to use UpdateContext instead of Set. `UpdateContext({varStatusUpdate:Text("Pending Approval")})`.  Not sure why you're using the text function here, however. 

If you need more help, I think we need a better understanding of what is actually happening on your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I could get this to work was to use the patch command like below:

```
Patch('LTRequest', ThisItem,{
   SubmitDate: Now(),Status:Text("Pending Approval")});
Back();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of updating the logic and the value from a Datacard in your form to a datasource is to change the **Update** property for a specific Datacard

Example -
Originally:

[image]

Changing the Update values:

[image]

or

[image]

Where **DataCardValue2_6.Text** is the text input for the column.